# Question on Combinations

Tags: geometry, combinations

There are $10$ points in a plane, no three of which are in the same straight line, except $4$ points, which are collinear. Find the number of straight lines obtained from the pairs of these points? Answer is $40$.  I didn't get it how, please someone help me.

Comment: There are 45 unordered pairs of points, but 6 of these pairs all define the 4-point line ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If no points were collinear, the number of lines would be
$$\binom {10}2=45$$
Since four points are collinear, we count $\binom 42=6$ lines only as $1$, so we get
$$
45-6+1=40
$$

Comment: This method nicely extends to cases with multiple sets of collinear points. (The brute force approach I stated in my answer doesn't.)

Answer (score 0):

Start with a line with four points on it. Adding a fifth point allows us to draw a line through each of the four collinear points. Adding a sixth point lets us draw straight lines through the collinear, but also through the fifth point. We repeat this up to the tenth point, and then count up all these lines to give the total.